# Keeping textbox value persevered in layout on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout

In the layout page I have a text box which defines the currency used in every page. I want to keep that textbox value preserved while going from one form to another form as every time form transaction happens it reloads the layout page and clears the textbox. I was looking around for a solution in which the layout page won't load on every page transaction as it is creating overhead.

The solution I found is using **pjax** but I believe there should be some other solution inside MVC. So I need a solution for any of the 2 parts:

1) To preserve textbox value of the layout on every page transaction OR

2) Make the layout not load on every page transaction

Comment: You could, maybe, create custom action filter for setting your data in ViewBag property on actions that you use and get your currency value from ViewBag. Do you need your textbox value on every page of your application or just specific?

Comment: Viewbag wont be appropriate for me as I am trying to create E-commerce website for multiple countries I want to show it in Dropdown but textbox i write is just to get solution for it. I fit goes with textbox I will manage it with dropdown

Comment: Why won't? You put your selected value you wish to preserve in view bag and set it as selected on view. Or you can put your selected value in View Model and set your dropdown selected value from there.

Comment: Dont u think preserving the value and setting it again at every page load is just a overhead. It will be ok if its just one or few textbox. If there is more data it will start loading slowly. So I would prefer that layout page doesnt load at all at every page transaction once it load thats it like master page in asp.net

Comment: I want some efficient way for doing that

Comment: But that's the way how web applications are working. HTTP is stateless protocol, that is the mechanism for passing values between calls.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

Comment: Ok if I use viewbag in layout its value will be preserved cause using viewbag in form clears the value everytime form loads

Comment: You must pass that value from your controller action to view. Either in viewbag or viewmodel, or any other available resources in mvc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a partial action and then call it from your views.

```
<input type="text" name="currency" value="@Html.Action("GetCurrentCurrency","Currency");" />
```

Comment: No dude this is totally wrong thing. You are not even close to what i want

Comment: @Snehal, look nopcommerce.com in Nop.Web project, CommonController for its CurrencySelector action which serves user current currency, I meant something like that.